# How to update array from method using abstraction

Tags: java, arrays, abstraction

My goal is to create an atm program using Java techniques like encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism and what i use is the last, abstraction. When I enter a value on the withdraw or deposit value, it does its job, but when I click on the main menu the button for the balance inquiry, the balance doesn't update.

```
/*
* abstraction
*/
package atm;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class atm {
    int[] an = {201511032,201563244,201410230,201596427,201456329};
    int[] pin = {8888,1234,5432,9876,6543};
    int[] ac = {80500,3000,27450,6500,13200};
    public static void main(String args[]){
        atm obj = new atm();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Welcome!");
        System.out.println("\n[0] To end Transaction\n");
        System.out.print("ENTER ACCOUNT NUMBER: ");
        int acc = sc.nextInt();
        if (acc == 0){System.exit(acc);}
        System.out.print("ENTER PIN NUMBER: ");
        int pass = sc.nextInt();
        obj.accVer(pass, acc);
    }
    void accVer(int pass, int acc){
        atm obj = new atm();
        if (acc == an[0] && pass==pin[0]){
            System.out.println("");
            obj.mMenu(an[0],pin[0],0);
        }else if (acc == an[1] && pass==pin[1]){
            System.out.println("");
            obj.mMenu(an[1],pin[1],1);
        }else if (acc == an[2] && pass==pin[2]){
            System.out.println("");
            obj.mMenu(an[2],pin[2],2);
        }else if (acc == an[3] && pass==pin[3]){
            System.out.println("");
            obj.mMenu(an[3],pin[3],3);
        }else if (acc == an[4] && pass==pin[4]){
            System.out.println("");
            obj.mMenu(an[4],pin[4],4);
        }else{
            System.out.println("Error Account Number or Pin. \nPlease Try Again\n");
            atm.main(null);
        }
    }
    void mMenu(int pass, int acc, int num1){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Main Menu: ");
        System.out.println("[1] for Balance Inquiry");
        System.out.println("[2] for Withdraw");
        System.out.println("[3] for Deposit");
        System.out.println("[4] for End Transaction");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        int s = sc.nextInt();
        methods obj = new execute();
        if (s == 1){obj.balanceInquiry(pass, acc, num1);}
        else if(s == 2){obj.withdrawal(pass, acc, num1);}
        else if(s == 3){obj.deposit(pass, acc, num1);}
        else{System.out.println("Thank You!");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");atm.main(null);}
    }
    void withprod(int with, int pass, int acc, int num1){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        methods obj1 = new execute();
        atm obj = new atm();
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Do you wish to Withdraw this amount?: $ "+with);
        System.out.println("[1] for Yes");
        System.out.println("[2] for No");
        System.out.print("Choice: ");
        int ans = sc.nextInt();
        if (ans == 1){
            int num4 = ac[num1]-with;
            ac[num1] = num4;
            System.out.println("The Transaction has been made. \nPlease get the money on the dispenser window.");
            System.out.println("");
            obj.mMenu(pass, acc, num1);
        }else if(ans == 2){
            obj1.withdrawal(pass,acc,num1);
        }   
    }


    abstract class methods{
        abstract void balanceInquiry(int pass, int acc, int num1);
        abstract void withdrawal(int pass, int acc, int num1);
        abstract void deposit(int pass, int acc, int num1);

    }
    class execute extends methods{

        @Override
        void balanceInquiry(int pass, int acc, int num1) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            atm obj = new atm();
            System.out.println("Current Balance: $" +ac[num1]);
            System.out.print("press any number to return: ");
            int ans = sc.nextInt();
            if (ans < 10){System.out.println("");obj.mMenu(pass, acc, num1);}
            else{obj.mMenu(pass, acc, num1);}
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("");
        }

        @Override
        void withdrawal(int pass, int acc, int num1) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            methods obj1 = new execute();
            atm obj = new atm();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("MENU FOR WITHDRAWAL");
            System.out.println("[0] to Return");
            System.out.println("[2] to $ 20");
            System.out.println("[2] to $ 40");
            System.out.println("[3] to $ 60");
            System.out.println("[4] to $ 100");
            System.out.println("[5] to $ 200");
            System.out.println("[6] to Other Amount");
            System.out.print("Please choose your desire answer: ");

            int ans = sc.nextInt();
            if (ans == 0){obj.mMenu(pass,acc,num1);}
            else if (ans == 1){int with = 20;obj.withprod(with,pass,acc,num1);}
            else if (ans == 2){int with = 40;obj.withprod(with,pass,acc,num1);}
            else if (ans == 3){int with = 60;obj.withprod(with,pass,acc,num1);}
            else if (ans == 4){int with = 100;obj.withprod(with,pass,acc,num1);}
            else if (ans == 5){int with = 200;obj.withprod(with,pass,acc,num1);}
            else if (ans == 6){System.out.print("Please enter the amount you wish to Withdraw: $ ");int with = sc.nextInt(); obj.withprod(with,pass,acc,num1);}
            else{System.out.println("ERROR: Invalid Input.\n Please Try Again");obj1.withdrawal(pass, acc, num1);}
        }

        @Override
        void deposit(int pass, int acc, int num1) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            methods obj1 = new execute();
            atm obj = new atm();
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("MENU FOR DEPOSIT");
            System.out.println("[0] to Return");
            System.out.print("Please enter the amount you wish to deposit: $ ");
            int dep = sc.nextInt();
            if (dep == 0){obj.mMenu(pass,acc,num1);}
            else{
                System.out.println("");
                System.out.println("Do you wish to deposit this amount?: $ "+dep);
                System.out.println("[1] for Yes");
                System.out.println("[2] for No");
                System.out.print("Choice: ");
                int ans = sc.nextInt();
                if (ans == 1){
                    System.out.println("Please use the envelope given, insert the amount and place it in the deposit bin.");
                    System.out.println("Have you placed the envelope on the deposit bin?: ");
                    System.out.println("[1] for Yes");
                    System.out.println("[2] for No");
                    int ans2 = sc.nextInt();
                    if (ans2 == 1){
                        System.out.println("We recieved your deposit. Please check your balance for updates.");
                        float num2 = ac[num1]+dep;
                        ac[num1] = (int) num2;
                        System.out.println("");
                        obj.mMenu(pass, acc, num1);
                    }else{obj1.deposit(pass, acc, num1);}
                }else if(ans == 2){
                    obj1.deposit(pass,acc,num1);
                }
            }   
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand your code, the `withdraw` and  `disposit` methods do not share any information with the `atm`-Class nor with the between each other. Your `execute` class is pretty completely stateless (which is often fine). But you need some state, and for that you try to achieve that by constructing new instances of your classes, but on that can't save any state:

```
    void withdrawal(int pass, int acc, int num1) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            methods obj1 = new execute();
            atm obj = new atm();
```

Your code should be refactored on many places, but for a first hotfix: Extend your methods with `myAtm` :

```
        abstract void balanceInquiry(int pass, int acc, int num1, atm myAtm );
        abstract void withdrawal(int pass, int acc, int num1, atm myAtm);
        abstract void deposit(int pass, int acc, int num1, atm myAtm);
```

call them like `obj.balanceInquiry(pass, acc, num1, this)` in your `atm` class and replace all  `atm obj = new atm()`; with `atm obj = myAtm` .

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you create a new atm object in most of your methods by calling `new atm()`. That way you only operate on that instance, which is not shared between the methods.